# Configuring Ceph VFS on Samba

Tags: samba, ceph

I'm trying to share out a CephFS filesystem via Samba using the vfs module, but the instructions I can find are all pretty minimal and nothing I have tried works.

So far, I have an entry in my smb.conf along the lines of

```
[CephFS]
path=/
vfs objects = acl_xattr ceph
ceph:config_file = /etc/ceph/cephsamba.conf
```

the ceph:config_file having been suggested as an option from this [site](https://www.mankier.com/8/vfs_ceph).

What that site doesn't do is give any indication of what the contents of that file should be and I can't find any references anywhere else.

I can mount the CephFS directly onto a mountpoint on the system and share it out via Samba from there, but I was under the impression that it could be done directly via the VFS module.

If anyone could provide me with some insight/direction on how to get this shared it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The config file option, if specified, needs to point to the config file for the ceph cluster, which has a working cephfs filesystem, that you want samba to work with.

If you don't already have a running ceph cluster, with a cephfs filesystem, this samba vfs module isn't for you.

Comment: @Thomas: "If […], this samba vfs module isn't for you" looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)